# Cherry Tomato plants, withering, yellowing leaves, white powdery on root

Tags: diagnosis, plant-care, tomatoes, container-gardening, roots

[image]

[image]

The plant is yellowing, and pull out the root to find the white powdering thing... Anyone know what is this? how to prevent?

Comment: Good question and good illustrations; could also be helpful if could include illustration of top of yellowing Tomato plant, watering amount & frequency, and if coarse gravel in bottom of container for good drainage & good aereation. Thank you. Welcome to the site!